# Unique solutions to a nonlinear system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, and $f: R\rightarrow R^n$ is continuous and bounded.

(a) If $A$ has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, prove that $\dot{x} = Ax + f(t)$ has a unique solution which is bounded on $R$.

(b) Show the counterexample to (a) when $A$ has eigenvalues on the imaginary axis.

**My attempt:** (a) Since $A$ has no eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, $A$ is infinitesimally hyperbolic. By a well-know theorem,  we can rewrite a Jordan canonical form  $J$ of $A$ such that $J = [A_s\  0, 0\  A_u]^T$ where eigenvalues of matrix $A_s$ all have negative real parts and eigenvalues of $A_u$ all have positive real parts.  Then the given ODE is equivalent to: $\dot{x} = PJP^{-1}x + f(t)$ where $P$ is matrix whose columns are eigenvectors associated with each eigenvalues of $A_s, A_u$ in the same order.

My question is: how to show that $PJP^{-1}$ transforms $A$ into 2 block matrices: one with all eigenvalues having positive real part, and one with all eigenvalues having negative real parts?

(b) I haven't been able to get this, despite spending several hours trying to find $A$ so that the solutions would have resonance effect. Can someone please give some thought about this?

Comment: (b) what if 
$A = \left[ \begin {array}{cc} 0&0\\ 1&0\end {array}
 \right]$ 
and $f(t) = [ 1 \ \ \ 1]^T$ ?

Comment: @Guignol: Such a slick example! Although I'm not sure if $\lambda = 0$ counts as "on the imaginary axis," but I guess the origin still counts:) Many thanks! Can you try part (a) as well?

Comment: nobody wants to help me with part (a), after transforming $A$ into the Jordan form? I just need to prove if there exists a relationship between the solution of $\dot{x} = Ax + f(t)$ and $\dot{x} = A_sx + f(t)$ or $\dot{x} = A_ux + f(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assertion in (a) is wrong. You need to have eigenvalues with negative real part for a bounded solution for all possible bounded $f(t)$.

As for the Jordan form you can write
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}P_s & P_u\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}A_s & 0 \\ 0 & A_u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}P_s & P_u\end{bmatrix}^{-1} $$

where columns of $P_s$ and $P_u$ contains the (generalized) eigenvectors of the stable and unstable eigenvalues respectively. You can see this fact from the spectral decomposition of a matrix.

Now define $P = \begin{bmatrix}P_s & P_u\end{bmatrix}$ and $y = P^{-1} x$.

$$\dot{y} = P^{-1} \dot{x} = P^{-1} A x + P^{-1} f(t) = P^{-1} A P y + P^{-1} f(t)$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{y}_s \\ \dot{y}_u\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}A_s & 0 \\ 0 & A_u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}y_s \\ y_u\end{bmatrix} + P^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}f_s(t) \\ f_u(t) \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I'm not sure why (a) is wrong from your explanation. Can you clarify with a counterexample? Yes, I can see how you rewrite A in that form, but I need to show that from that form, i can break the original ODEs into 2 sub-ODEs, each correspond to either $A_s$ or $A_u$. It's quite hard:(

Comment: For counter example select $A=1$ and $f(t)=1$. Ok, I understand the question now, see updated answer.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful! The transformation is so simple that I should have thought of it:(( Many thanks for your great help. Btw, is the last term still bounded, as the columns of $P^{-1}$ might contain unstable eigenvalues?

Comment: Multiplication with a constant never changes the boundedness of a function. The bound might be bigger but still finite and that's what is important.

Comment: I have a quick question: for the 2nd ODEs above, to show there is an unique bounded solution for $\dot{y_u} = A_uy_u + P^{-1}f_u(t)$, it's easy for $t\geq 0$. For $t\leq 0$, I rewrite the DE by letting $\tau = -t$. Since the equation holds for $t\geq 0$,  replacing $t$ by $\tau$, we get: $-\dot{y_u(-t)} = Ay_u(-t) + f(-t)$ for $t\leq 0$.  There is an unique bounded solution $y(t)$ to $\dot{y(t)} = Ay(t) + f(t)$ FOR $t\geq 0$ => $-y(t)$ is a unique bounded solution to $\dot{y(t)} = -Ay(t) - f(t)$ FOR $t\geq 0$. Let $y_u(-t) = -y(t)$, so $y_u(-t)$ is an unique and bounded solution for $t\leq 0$.

Comment: Also, if $A_u$ has all eigenvalues of negative real parts, it's NOT true that $-A_u$ has all eigenvalues of POSITIVE real parts?

Comment: I realized that my solution above, even though it shows the existence of an unique bounded solution on $\mathbb{R}$ for cases when $t\geq 0$ and $t\leq 0$, it cannot prove that these two solutions coincide, so existence of unique solution is not guaranteed across $\mathbb{R}$. Can you please help me with the 2nd ODE?

Comment: I really wonder how the solution to the 2nd ODE can be bounded for $t\leq 0$? Shouldn't the general solution part ($e^{At}$) to the homogeneous portion of the ODE blows up as $t<0$ and A has all eigenvalues with negative real parts?

Comment: There is no LTI system exists that the solutions are bounded for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. This is why you need to start from a $t_0$ and assume $x(t) = 0, \forall t < t_0$. It is called causality assumption. Even so, solutions of a LTI system with a bounded input function $f(t)$ are bounded if and only if the matrix $A$ has eigenvalues with negative real part. This is why (a) is wrong. Select $A=1$ and $f(t)=1$. The solution is clearly unbounded for any initial state.

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarification. But I was able to show there is a biunded solution in the case $t < 0$ above for $A_s$. Only the uniqueness part doesn't hold. Can you give a matrix $A$ having $A_s$ as above, but solution is not bounded for the case above? How about the hypothesis about the signs of eigenvalues of $-A_s$?

Comment: Here's the strong theorem (simplified version) I used to prove there is a unique bounded solution when $A$ has eigenvalues with positive real part: "Consider the DE: $\dot{x} = Ax+ f(t)$ where $f: R\rightarrow R^n$ is continuous. Assume that for some constants $\lambda \in R$, $K\geq 1$, $M\geq 0$ and $\gamma < \lambda$, the following estimates hold: 1. $||e^{At}||\leq Ke^{\lambda t}$ for EVERY $t\leq 0$, 2. $||f(t)||\leq Me^{\gamma t}$ for $t\in R$. Then there exists EXACTLY ONE solution $x$ satisfied  $||x(t)||\leq e^{\lambda t}\frac{KM}{\lambda - \gamma - KL}$ for ALL $t\in R$."

Comment: You can see why there is a difference between when $A$ has eigenvalues with positive and negative real parts. The reason is in the case of positive real parts, I can always set $\gamma = 0$, and only need to chose $\lambda$ sufficiently large so that inequality (1) has $K\geq 1$ (we can do this easily by another well-known result).  And $M$ exists simply because $f(t)$ is bounded, and we can use $L^{\infty}-$ norm by norm-equivalence in finite dimensional space. But this trick cannot work for the case with negative real parts unfortunately. But your counter-example contradicts to the theorem?

Comment: Obviously, we have different definitions of boundedness. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function. The theorem you provided is true but it isn't a "bound" as it grows exponentially. Also it is true that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $-A$, which is easy to prove. Also see that $A_s = -1$ and $f(t)=1$ is unbounded (which means keeps growing forever) for $t \in (-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: But if $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $-A$, then all we need to do is to switch the time $t$ by $-t$ for $t\leq 0$, and proceed by applying the theorem I showed above (because at that time, $-A_s$ would have ALL eigenvalues of positive real parts => Done!) I also found that example for $A_s$, so now the problem statement is quite confusing to me... I meant, if you look at it as $||x(t)||e^{\lambda t}$ where $\lambda = 0, t< 0$, then it's really a "bound." I think the question uses the same definition of boundedness as on the Wiki. Now I question the validity of this

Comment: so I understand that bounded in $R$ here meant it is bounded by some function in $R$. That function should only be depended on $t$. If that's the case, I think we can do this problem by using the trick of "replacing t by -t$, so that $\dot{u_s(-t)} =  - A_s\ u_s(-t) + P^{-1}f_s(-t)$. Now since $-A$ has all eigenvalues with positive real parts, we can use the theorem above, and obtain what we need (Q.E.D). Am I correct here?

Comment: are you tired of this problem, due to our divergence in the definition of boundedness? Please help bear with me if you can.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. Read everything I wrote carefully and do the counter examples. (a) is obviously wrong. That's it. Trying to prove a wrong expression is meaningless. Also, if boundedness means bounded by some function, the claim would be true even if $A$ has eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, i.e. for all $A$.