# Conditions on initial value for system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Given $\dot{x} = x - y + e^{-t}$ and $\dot{y} = x+y + e^{-t}$. Find the set of initial conditions at $t = 0$ s.t $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} (x(t), y(t)) = (0, 0)$ whenever $(x(t), y(t))$ satisfies one of these initial conditions.

**My progress:** After using the "Variation Of Parameters" formula (aka, solutions to the ODE: $\dot{x} = A(t)x + g(t,x)$, have the form: $\phi(t) = \gamma(t)\gamma^{-1}(t_0)x_0 + \gamma(t)\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \gamma^{-1}(s)g(\phi(s), s)ds$, where $\gamma(t) =$ fundamental matrix solution to $\dot{x} = Ax$). Now, by letting $z_1 = x, z_2 = y$, and doing a bunch of algebraic manipulations, I ended up with the solution:

$z(t) = [z_{01}cos(t) - sin(t)(z_{02} + \frac{2(i-1)}{5}), sin(t)(z_{01}+\frac{1-i}{5})+ z_{02}cos(t)]$ where $z(0) = [z_{01} \ z_{02}]$.

Hopefully this is correct, as I checked over my computations several times.
If that's the case, we see that for $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} (x(t), y(t)) = (0, 0)$, we need: $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} z(t) = (0, 0)$. But as $t\rightarrow \infty$, $\cot(t)$ oscillates between $(-\infty, \infty)$, and $z_{01}, z_{02}$ are some fixed numbers at $t = 0$, how can $\frac{z_{02} \ +\  \frac{2(i-1)}{5}}{z_{01}} = \cot{t}$ in that case? We cannot really let $z_{01} = 0, z_{02} = \frac{-2(i-1)}{5}$ as well, because then the 2nd component of $z(t)$ is not satisfies.

From these observations, I think there doesn't really exist any set of initial conditions that gives $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} (x(t), y(t)) = (0, 0)$, which is weird:P

**My question:** Can anyone please give this problem a try to see if my conclusion above is correct? Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with this problem? The problem is that despite reviewing my computations for several times, I couldn't see where i made a mistake when computing the "Variation of parameters" formula:P

Comment: @NormalHuman: can you please give this problem a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are obviously wrong, because you shouldn't have imaginary part in your solution. See that

$$e^{At} = e^{t} \begin{bmatrix} \cos t & -\sin t \\\sin t & \cos t \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, observe that

$$z(t) = e^{At} z(0) + \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} e^{-s} ds$$

The integral part will contain the exponential term $e^{-t}$ after integrating, so it will go to $0$ at infinity. Since, $\lim e^{At} = \infty$, the only choice is $z(0) = 0$.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for your great explanation. I made this stupid mistake: $e^{(1+i)t} \neq cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ when calculating the integral that made everything go wrong:(( I know it's so shameful to ask this, but can you give me some help again with this problem for part (a) only: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1484079/unique-solutions-to-a-nonlinear-system-of-odes?noredirect=1#comment3022731_1484079

Comment: Wait a minute... How did you do the integral of a $e^{-As}e^{-s}$ in this case to show that it has an exponential term $e^{-t}$ after integrating? I don't think it makes sense to integrate in a normal way??

Comment: and $\lim e^{At}$ where $t\rightarrow \infty$ is bounded (well-known result, as all the eigenvalues of $A$ in this case has the real parts bounded), so your conclusion is not quite correct? Unless you can show that $e^{At}\neq 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Each element of the matrix $e^{-As} e^{-s}$ contains something like $e^{-2s} \cos s$ or $e^{-2s} \sin s$. After integrating it will contain $e^{-2s} (a \cos s + b \sin s)$ where $s$ runs from $0$ to $t$. So, after multiplying with $e^{At}$ from the left, each element will contain something like $e^{-t} (a \cos t + b \sin t)$.

Comment: The limit exists if and only if all $A$ have eigenvalues with negative real parts or non-defective 0 eigenvalues. It is not related to the "boundedness" of eigenvalues.

Comment: So there was a theorem like: "if the real parts of all eigenvalues of $A$ are between $[a, b]$ for $-\infty < a\leq b < \infty$, then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $K>0$ such that $||e^{(At)}||\leq Ke^{(a-\epsilon)t}$ for every $t\leq 0$, and $||e^{(At)}||\leq Ke^{(b+\epsilon)t}$ for every $t\geq 0$." So your conclusion about the limit contradicts to this theorem?

Comment: No, it does not contradict with this theorem. This theorem is true for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, but the limit does not exists (because it isn't finite) as $t$ goes to infinity when the real part is positive. $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain infinity.

Comment: how can a limit exist when a norm is bounded by some finite numbers??I'm so stupid:(...But look at the form of your solution, you're definitely right, since each entry would blow up when $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Put any finite $t$ in the theorem an it is true regardless of how big the numbers are. Even if the numbers are growing exponentially fast, they are still finite for a finite $t$. Infinity is a different story and it is a bit hard to get your head around at first. I suggest you do some reading on infinity, as you will constantly be using the concept.

Comment: I actually got it. An easy way to check is plugging in $t\rightarrow \infty$, and see the RHS blows up when $\epsilon$ is large. Thank you so much for your patience. Great solution btw!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure about your solution, however I will give you a few hints.

Notice that this is nonhomogeneous linear differential equation, so the general solution would contain a linear combination of the solutions to the homogeneous differential equation and the particular solution, which satisfies the nonhomogeneity.

Do you have to find the complete solutions to homogeneous differential equation? Because only the solution corresponding to eigenvalues with negative real parts will disappear at $t\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. If you tried computing the solutions to the homogeneous DEs above, you would get the two eigenvalues are $1-i$ and $1+i$ => The fundamental matrix solution to the homogeneous part is: $F(t) = [ie^{(1+i)t}\ -ie^{(1-i)t}, e^{(1+i)t}\ e^{(1-i)t}]^T$. This is NOT the complete solutions, but as you can see in this case, ALL the solutions to the homogeneous DE must contain the term $e^{t}$, so nothing will disappear as $t\rightarrow \infty$. I hope you can work out more details. Please let me know if I missed something.

Comment: Your first hint is essentially the same as the "variation of parameters" formula that I used above. So not quite helpful in this case:(

Comment: @user177196 Like I stated in my answer, I am not sure of your solution is correct, since I would expect it to be real. With this I mean that real initial conditions always yield a completely real solution, but your solution seems to complex. Also have you tried to substitute your solution back into the differential equation?

Comment: Those eigenvalues and conclusions are correct. But if the solution can not contain any combination of the solution to the homogeneous differential, then what which expression is still left? Also note that a homogeneous differential equation, with all its eigenvalues having a real part bigger than zero, will still go to $\vec{0}$ at $t\to\infty$ if the initial condition is $\vec{0}$.

Comment: thanks for your great observation on separating the solutions. I tried picking the first column of $F(t)$ above (so the general solutions to the homogeneous DE have the form $C[ie^{(1+i)t}\  e^{(1+i)t}]$. The value of $C$ depends on the initial condition $x(0)$. Now, for the inhomogeneous equation $\dot{x} = Ax + e^{-t}$ with initial value $x(0)$, I get the solution is $C[ie^{(1+i)t}\  e^{(1+i)t}] \int_{0}^{t} 1/C [\frac{1}{ie^{(1+i)s}}\  \frac{1}{e^{(1+i)s}}]^T [e^{-s} \ e^{-s}]ds$. I find this weird because I have to take the inverse of $C[ie^{(1+i)t}\  e^{(1+i)t}]$, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I'd love to see your proof for ONE case on how you actually separated one column of the fundamental matrix solution + a specific solution for the inhomogeneous one. Please help if you can.